# Tic tac toe C++ overwriting the board

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

Hi so I have it set up the way I want to for the most part.  The last part I'm trying to implement is to have it so the input does not overwrite itself when input either `X`or `0`.  If someone could take a look at it and tell me what exactly I did wrong with my noRepeat function I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int ROWS = 3;
const int COLS = 3;
char Player1 = 'X';
char Player2 = 'O';
int row, col;
char board[3][3]= { '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'};  //Game board


//Prototypes

void noRepeat();
void drawBoard();
void selection(int&, int&);
char winner();
void switchPlayer();

int main()
{
    cout << "Tic Tac Toe!" << endl << endl;

    drawBoard();
    cout << endl << endl;
    while (1)
    {

        if ( noRepeat() )
        {
            selection(row, col);
            drawBoard();
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if (winner() == 'X')
        {
            cout << "Player 1 wins!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (winner() == 'O')
        {
            cout << "Player 2 wins!" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }


    return 0;
}


// input function
void selection(int &row, int &col)
{
    cout << "Enter a number for row between 0 - 2" << endl;
    cin >> row;
    if (row < 0 || row > 2) {
        cout << "Invalid selection select a row between 0 - 2" << endl;
        cin >> row;
    }

    cout << "Enter a number for col between 0 - 2" << endl;
    cin >> col;
    if (col < 0 || col > 2) {
        cout << "Invalid selection select a row between 0 - 2" << endl;
        cin >> col;
    }



    if (row == 0 && col == 0)
        board[0][0] = Player1;
    else if (row == 0 && col == 1)
        board[0][1] = Player1;
    else if (row == 0 && col == 2)
        board[0][2] = Player1;
    else if (row == 1 && col == 0)
        board[1][0] = Player1;
    else if (row == 1 && col == 1)
        board[1][1] = Player1;
    else if (row == 1 && col == 2)
        board[1][2] = Player1;
    else if (row == 2 && col == 0)
        board[2][0] = Player1;
    else if (row == 2 && col == 1)
        board[2][1] = Player1;
    else if (row == 2 && col == 2)
        board[2][2] = Player1;


}


//Board function
 void drawBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


//Function to switch between X's and O's

void switchPlayer() {

    char temp = Player1;
    if (Player1) {
        Player1 = Player2;
    }

    if (Player2)
    {
        Player2 = temp;
    }
}


//conditional winner checker
char winner() {
    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[1][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[2][0] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][0] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][1] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[2][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

//Player 2
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[1][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[2][0] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][0] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][1] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[2][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
}


//Function to prevent overwriting.
void noRepeat() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == Player1 || board[i][j] == Player2) {
                cout << "Invalid selection, please choose a row and column 
again."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ( noRepeat() )` - but `noRepeat` is `void` - does that even compile? Also cut your `winner()` in half by passing in `'X'` or `'O'` as a parameter and using the same logic for both.

Comment: Here's a protip: when you get things like this its a great idea to print whats in the array to see exactly whats going on.  Add log lines to see which path the code takes to understand what is happening.  Then you will have gained a skill that will help you fix many many bugs.  If you're using an IDE like Visual Studio or Netbeans then learn how to step into your code and add watches on variables.  These things I'm mentioning is all part of what we call "debugging".  Its a normal part of programming. Good luck.

Comment: I also recommend to download & install  Visual Studio 2017 Community. It's a full-functionality version, & free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `noRepeat()` returns `void`. But must return `boolean` type.

Answer (score 1):

(1) When a player select Row/Col, it necessary to check that the array has '*' char in that selection (i.e. unused yet). (2) Add an int variable 'selections' and on any valid selection increment it by 1. When selection hits 9, the board is full. Like that, you don't need `noRepeat()` at all.

The `noRepeat()` function just print but return void. So what is the purpose of asking `if (noRepeat())`?

The function `switchPlayer()` does nothing. This one below, for example, if you pass the "current player", returns the other one: *..Use: (1) Add `char currentPalayer = Player1;` variable, and (2) `currentPalayer = switchPlayer(currentPalayer);` when you want to switch player. Use the `currentPalayer` variable, when `Player1` and `Player2` can be `const char` of `#define`*

```
char switchPlayer(char currentPlayer) {

    const int K = Player1 + Player2;

    return (char) (K - currentPlayer);
}
```

I guess there are more issues.

BTW: Cut to 1/2 the winner() function:

```
//conditional winner checker
char winner() {
    if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2])
        return board[0][0];
    if (board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[1][2])
        return board[1][0];
    if (board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][1] ==board[2][2]))
        return board[2][0];

    if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[1][0] == board[2][0])
        return board[0][0] ;
    if (board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1])
        return board[0][1];
    if (board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[1][2] == board[2][2])
        return board[0][2];

    if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])
        return board[0][0];
    if (board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[0][2])
        return board[2][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can all suggest improvements to your code and perhaps it should be handled over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Short of doing a major recode, let's look at doing minor tweaks to one of your functions:

```
void selection(int &row, int &col)
{
    cout << "Enter a number for row between 0 - 2" << endl;
    cin >> row;
    while (row < 0 || row > 2) {
        cout << "Invalid selection select a row between 0 - 2" << endl;
        cin >> row;
    }

    cout << "Enter a number for col between 0 - 2" << endl;
    cin >> col;
    while (col < 0 || col > 2) {
        cout << "Invalid selection select a row between 0 - 2" << endl;
        cin >> col;
    }

    board[row][col] = Player1;
}
```

What I have done to your function was change the validation logic from `if` to `while` loop since you want to keep asking until you received a valid input. The other thing was I refactor away your setter. Why have all those `if` variations when a single 1-liner `board[row]col] = Player;` can do the same job?

Overall, I didn't like this function because there's a missed opportunity to do validation for `'*'` here. I cannot demonstrate that without rewriting a larger portion of that function.

Other issues I had with the code was:

- The handling of 'X' and 'O'. I would have gone with `int currentPlayer` whose value was either 0 or 1. You could have implemented a `char playerMarker[2] = { 'X', 'O' };` lookup so the correct symbol gets used when a move is made.
- The switching player logic is wrong.  You only need one variable, you have two and it over complicated things. If you only have one variable, you could have implemented it as a 1 liner: e.g. `currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer;`
- The board itself, I would have gone with `char board[ROW][COL + 2];` and added a LF and NUL terminator then printing the board would have been just print 3 strings: `puts(board[0]); puts(board[1]); puts(board[2]);`
- The winning condition has already been refactored by another user
- There's no check for stalemate. Which, most players of TIC-TAC-TOE rapidly reach
- The implementation of `noRepeat` makes no sense.